# styling in text (textView)

Tags: android

Android,How to do styling in textView . I want to style the text of textView, i am trying style for textView (text) border means suppose i have written "HELLO" in white color and font is bold so,now i want to make a border (style) on "HELLO" with red color but i don't understand how to do that ? I tried a lot but it won't work as i want it and there are so many errors in my code ...Please help me ..!

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <resources>
            <style>
                <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
                <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
                <item name="android:capitalize">characters</item>
                <item name="android:textSize">12pt</item>
                <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>/>
                 <item name="android:textborderColor">#ff00ff</item>
            </style>
        </resources>
```

Comment: I highly recommend you read the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) around Themes and Styles. One quick fix is your color values should be defined using hexadecimal. `#ffooff` is not a valid color - you are looking to use `#ff00ff`

Comment: Thanks for guiding me...but I have already correct it .

Answer (score 0):

you can use style like this , In style xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
        <style name="newtextview" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Textview">
            <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
            <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
            <item name="android:capitalize">characters</item>
            <item name="android:textSize">12pt</item>
            <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>/>
             <item name="android:textborderColor">#ff00ff</item>
        </style>
    </resources>
```

and use like this :

```
<Textview
  android:id="@+id/tv"
  style="@style/edt_text"
  android:textColor="#616161" 
/>
```